# Why is Google PubSub always creating 60 permanent threads?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

My application publishes a low volume of messages (1 every few seconds at most).  It does not subscribe.

On first use, PubSub  creates 60 threads that stay live permanently, like these:

```
"grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-1 Id\u003d115 RUNNABLE (in native)...
"grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-10 Id\u003d160 RUNNABLE (in native)":...
....
"Gax-16 Id\u003d141 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@24f8d334": ...
"Gax-17 Id\u003d142 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@24f8d334":....
```

We are using Java code as in [this sample](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher). The Publisher object is retained for the lifetime of the process, as recommended [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/2342).

Sixty is a very high default.

Moreover, if I   `setExecutorThreadCount`  to 4 (code following), I still get an extra 26 permanent threads. Setting this thread-count to 1 or 2 still produces about 20 extra threads.

```
ExecutorProvider executorProvider = InstantiatingExecutorProvider.newBuilder().setExecutorThreadCount(4).build();
Publisher.Builder builder = Publisher.newBuilder(ProjectTopicName.of(proj, topic)).setExecutorProvider(executorProvider);
```

Our application is already thread-heavy and cannot tolerate more than one or two extra threads set aside for just PubSub.

How can this be solved? Is there documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PubSub team provided an answer on GitHub [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/6428). This allows PubSub to use only *one* additional thread, not the 20 or 60 as described above.

```
  final ExecutorProvider fixedExecutorProvider = FixedExecutorProvider.create(
        new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)); //adjust the size
  Publisher publisher =
        Publisher.newBuilder("topic_name")
            .setExecutorProvider(fixedExecutorProvider)
            .setChannelProvider(
                PublisherStubSettings.defaultGrpcTransportProviderBuilder()
                    .setExecutorProvider(fixedExecutorProvider)
                    .setChannelConfigurator(
                        new ApiFunction<ManagedChannelBuilder, ManagedChannelBuilder>() {
                          @Override
                          public ManagedChannelBuilder apply(
                              ManagedChannelBuilder managedChannelBuilder) {
                            NettyChannelBuilder nettyChannelBuilder =
                                (NettyChannelBuilder)
                                    managedChannelBuilder.executor(
                                        fixedExecutorProvider.getExecutor());
                            nettyChannelBuilder.eventLoopGroup(
                                new NioEventLoopGroup(1, fixedExecutorProvider.getExecutor()));
                              nettyChannelBuilder.channelType(
                                  NioSocketChannel.class); // Use EPoll if available, if using EPoll update above line to use EPollEventLoopGroup

                            return nettyChannelBuilder;
                          }
                        })
                    .build())
            .build();
    publisher.publish(PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(ByteString.copyFromUtf8("testdata")).build()).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single subscriber, it is the normal behavior to see 60-65 threads.

Because each subscriber needs a certain number of gRPC streams and for each stream we have:

1. A separate thread to receive messages from the stream
2. One thread pool to process callbacks
3. One thread pool to send ack/delay messages

It is possible to control the thread pools, but there has always been an issue of facing deadlock:

```
ExecutorProvider executorProvider =
   InstantiatingExecutorProvider.newBuilder()
  .setExecutorThreadCount(1)
  .build();

Publisher publisher =
    Publisher.defaultBuilder(ProjectTopicName.of(proj, topic)).setExecutorProvider(executorProvider).build();

Subscriber subscriber =
    Subscriber.defaultBuilder(ProjectTopicName.of(proj, topic)).setExecutorProvider(executorProvider).build();
```

Comment: As mentioned, my application does not subscribe at all.

Comment: Also, please explain why such a large number of threads is needed just for  publishing. I would understand three or four threads; and I would  understand an autoscaling pool; but 60 is ridiculous.